# Not able to import variable from a different class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication

I am going off of a login screen tempalte,a nd am trying to get a widget class for a button to just show the username input as an alert on the screen. The usernameinput widget is defined but when I import it, it does not work.

```
class _InputEmailState extends State<InputEmail> {

   final myController = new TextEditingController();
```

This is the part where I define the input, and this is where I import the class in the button widget:

```
import 'package:login_minimalist/widget/inputEmail.dart';
```

When I try and reference the myController.text value, I get the error

```
The getter 'myController' isn't defined for the class '_ButtonLoginState'.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_minimalist/widget/inputEmail.dart';

class ButtonLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ButtonLoginState createState() => ButtonLoginState();
}

class ButtonLoginState extends State<ButtonLogin> {
  @override
```

Here is the button widget code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, right: 50, left: 200),
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
    height: 50,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.blue[300],
          blurRadius: 10.0, // has the effect of softening the shadow
          spreadRadius: 1.0, // has the effect of extending the shadow
          offset: Offset(
            5.0, // horizontal, move right 10
            5.0, // vertical, move down 10
          ),
        ),
      ],
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    ),
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              // Retrieve the text the user has entered by using the
              // TextEditingController.
              content: Text(InputEmailState.getUsername),
            );
          },
        );

      },
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Sign in',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward,
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And here is the Input code:

```
class InputEmailState extends State<InputEmail> {

  final myController = new TextEditingController();

  getUsername() {
    return(myController.text);
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 50, right: 50),
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: TextField(
          controller: myController,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            fillColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            labelText: 'Student ID',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could we see `_ButtonLoginState` and also where you tried to acces to the controller why don't you use the Controller in `_ButtonLoginState`

Comment: Please add more code to your question. For instance, your error refers to a _ButtonLoginState, however, you never mention this.

Comment: Sure. The button Login State is just the class where my login button is in.                             `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_minimalist/widget/inputEmail.dart';

class ButtonLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ButtonLoginState createState() => ButtonLoginState();
}

class ButtonLoginState extends State<ButtonLogin> {
  @override`

Comment: If you don't mid, it would be better to edit your question and add the code there, as it leaves it easier to understand

Comment: I barely use stack overflow and I forgot you can do that, give me a sec, ill put this code into the main question

Comment: Also, add the code for the whole widget, or at least all relevant parts (build method, etc)

Comment: I really need the build method (or wherever) you call `myController.text value`. How is `myController` defined? It isn't enough just to add the class "signatures". Edit: Just updated. I'll check it out

Comment: I put in a bunch of code from both classes. By the way, the page where they are both on just calls the functions to display the widgets os there isnt any important info on there, hence why its not included.

Comment: You still haven't included anywhere where you directly try to access `myController`, the call that is causing the error. Can't you share a fully working example either as code, or better still, on dartpad? Also, I can't be sure since there's no implementation, but the line looks very wrong `InputEmailState.getUsername`. Though I don't think it's causing your problem.

Comment: You are right, InputEmailState.getUsername is the error. I was just trying different things at this point. This line is supposed to just get the MyController variable from the other class. This is the code I have been talking about, sorry I haven't been clear.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to access `_ButtonLoginState` from another class/file. However, in Dart, classes, members, variables, etc. that begin with an underline ("_") are [considered private](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts). You can't access them from a different file (except in some special situations with libraries).

To solve this, you can change the name of the class to `ButtonLoginState` and it should work.

EDIT: In response to more info:

You don't seem to have fully understood the concepts of State in a StatefulWidget. I would strongly recommend taking a good look through the [Flutter guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) on the subject.

There are many different ways of managing state and what I am going to explain is almost definitely not the best option most of the time (this was the introductory approach some time ago, but I can't even find the example anymore), however, it does work. For a more general option, I recommend [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

In your case, the problem starts with this: `Text(InputEmailState.getUsername)`. You're not calling `InputEmailState.getUsername`, you're simply passing a reference to it. You need to include parentheses to actually call it - `InputEmailState.getUsername()`.

However, this isn't the whole issue. You're trying to access this function using the name of the class, which means you're trying to use it as a [static method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods). However, its an instance method (ie: you need a specific instance of the class to access it. This is the state I was talking about.

To simply get access to the state object of a specific widget, you can use a Key (generally a GlobalKey). You can define this in a parent widget, for example, and pass it as the `key` parameter of your `InputEmail` widget and keep a reference in the parent class. Then, to get the username, you can call `<key>.currentState.getUsername()` which will return the instance value. The exact implementation varies, and I don't have your code to know how it should be implemented.

As I say, this isn't really the recommended approach anymore. I strongly recommend getting to grips with the state concept, then it should be obvious what the best approach is.

Comment: Thank you, but I think the error is still here. I have unprivated both the button and the input class and I am unfortunately getting the same error. I tried defining a getter in the input class and calling it in the button class but that didn't work either.

Comment: You aren't just calling `InputEmailState.myController`, right? You are correctly accessing an instance of InputEmailState?

Comment: I don't think I am doing the right thing. What would be the correct syntax? I was trying just "myController" and then I tried "inputEmail.myController".

Comment: How do you acquire your instance of InputEmailState? Are you using a GlobalKey or something similar?

Comment: Not sure, but this is the code at the start of the input class.                                `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InputEmail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  InputEmailState createState() => InputEmailState();
}


class InputEmailState extends State<InputEmail> {

  final myController = new TextEditingController();`

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the link you sent and yes you are correct I do not understand the State concept. I have years of programming experience but that is almost exclusively python so yeah I do have trouble with this stuff. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask for any more clarifications. As to Flutter state management, yes, it takes a bit of getting used to, but the most important concept is to (normally) move shared state to parent widgets (and I recommend using Provider to share it with child widgets again).

Comment: Hi, when you wrote "<key>.currentState.getUsername()" what did you mean by this. Should I actually put <key> in, or is that just a placeholder?

Comment: No, it's just a placeholder. You have to create a GlobalKey in your parent state, then pass this variable to the child widget and then use this variable to call currentState.